# Есть ли способ синглтон класс оставить в стеке?

Tags: c++, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования, singleton

Классическая реализация синглетоне такая(из банды четырёх):

> Singleton (одиночка) (130) Гарантирует, что некоторый класс может
> иметь только один экземпляр, и предоставляет глобальную точку доступа
> к нему.

```cpp
class Singleton {
public:
    static Singleton* Instance();
protected:
    Singleton();
private:
    static Singleton* _instance;
};
```

А реализация такова:

```cpp
Singleton* Singleton::_instance = nullptr;
Singleton* Singleton::Instance () {
    if (_instance == nullptr) {
        _instance = new Singleton;
    }
    return _instance;
}
```

Тогда, любой класс, кто обвязан одиночкой, автоматом всегда лежит в куче. Что делать если хотелось бы его переместить в стек, при условии что его глобальность не нужна?

Comment: И что это получится? **Глобальный** объект вы хотите сделать **локальным**?

Comment: @Harry при условии что его глобальность не нужна

Comment: Да, такая возможность есть. Просто... не делайте его глобальным. Создайте его на стеке и передавайте по ссылке, а паттерн уберите куда подальше.

Comment: Обычно удобно оставить за синглетоном только вторую часть "предоставляет глобальную точку доступа к нему". Тогда можно без проблем создавать объект на стеке или где нужно.

Comment: @user7860670 не совсем понимаю что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Ну часть с ленивой отложенной инициализацией выкидывайте `if (_instance == nullptr) {
        _instance = new Singleton;
    }` А `_instance` присваивайте указатель на объект на стеке. Положительный момент еще в том, что объект можно создавать не только посредством конструктора по-умолчанию.

Comment: Синглтон либо создают в куче, либо в статической памяти. Третьего не дано.

Comment: Не совсем понятна цель создавать синглтон на стеке. Но общий смысл - синглтон это объект, который можно создать только один. А где он размещен - абсолютно другой вопрос. Хотите на стеке - выделите на стеке память под объект (объявите локальный массив нужного размера), а потом размещайте свой синглтон в этой памяти через `placement new()`. Будет синглтон лежать на стеке - но только зачем все эти пляски с бубном?

Comment: *при условии что его глобальность не нужна* — давайте определимся. Вы хотите создавать в функции (возможно, не одной) экземпляры вашего класса, но так, чтобы в пределах одной функции мог быть только один такой экземпляр, но при этом в программе их может быть много (хоть в каждой функции...)?

Answer (score 1):

Синглетон Александреску:

```
class Singleton {
public:
    static Singleton* Instance() {
       static  Singleton ret;
       return & ret;
    }
protected:
    Singleton();
};
```

Экземпляр лежит не на стеке, а в сегменте статических переменных. С точки зрения избегания new/delete, это тоже самое.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, раз не нужна *"глоабльность"*, то нужен просто локальный `static`:

```cpp
void func() {
    // Инициализация только при первом проходе
    static const auto singleton = Singleton::instance();
    // Либо
    static const Singleton singleton;
    // Но это не стековая переменная, а статическая область памяти.
    // Если нужно просто избежать выделения памяти в куче, то 
    // ответ уже был дан ранее.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Вы хотите что-то такое?

```
class Instance {
public:
    Instance()
    {
        if (global_instance_.expired()) {
            instance_ = std::make_shared<Singleton>();
            global_instance_ = instance_;
        } else {
            instance_ = global_instance_.lock();
        }
    }
private:
    class Singleton {

    };

    std::shared_ptr<Singleton> instance_;
    static std::weak_ptr<Singleton> global_instance_;
};
```

Или, что аналогично, просто возвращайте `shared_ptr` в `Singleton::Instance()`.